# What is a "feed-through load" and how does it work?

Tags: rf-power, equipment, testing

While browsing some miscellaneous RF test equipment supplies I stumbled across a two-port component sold as a "feed-thru load".

Take for example the Pasternak PE6026 ([datasheet](https://www.pasternack.com/images/ProductPDF/PE6026.pdf)), which looks physically like an *attenuator* (a slightly extended barrel with an "SMA male to female coaxial interface") and is rated like an *attenuator* (e.g "handles up to 2 Watts") but does **not** specify any actual **attenuation** (e.g. in dB) and is described instead as a "terminator" or "load":

> Pasternack’s PE6026 is an RF feed-thru termination (also called RF feed-thru load) that operates from DC to 1,000 MHz and handles up to 2 Watts (CW). This feed-thru SMA load is designed to be used with test equipment, like oscilloscopes, to match the equipment to the 50 Ohm device under test (DUT).

How can something be both a "terminator" and also "feed-thru"?

Answer (score 4):

I think the correct way to understand this is basically as "a dummy load which makes it easy to measure the voltage across itself".

Likely as simple as:

[image: a 50ohm resistor in parallel with both a DUT signal source and a scope/analyzer]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8pF1n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That is, for a feed-through terminator, the input port provides a *characteristic* impedance load assuming the output port is connected to a load of (ideally) *infinite* impedance. So the terminator provides the whole load and only a ± open circuit (i.e. a non-load) is meant to be "fed" by it — power in, **voltage** [only] out.

As the quote in my question hints at, the idea is that this lets you connect a device-u'wanna-test (DUT) which is expecting a 50Ω load to something like a high-impedance oscilloscope input without a mismatch.

Whereas with an attenuator there's a more complicated resistor network which provides a load assuming its output is **also** a load of *characteristic* impedance. So the load is shared between the attenuator and what it feeds — power in, power [reduced] out.

Comment: This is correct. In particular, they're frequently used with oscilloscopes, which conventionally have 1 MΩ input impedance (though usually on a BNC connector, not SMA). [feel free to / please do add this to your answer]

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO Thanks for the confirmation. The note about oscilloscope usage is kind of already in the *question* — though admittedly that's my fault… the downside of figuring out an answer while typing up my own question :-)

Comment: Sounds like you're saying, that a feed through test load, is designed to be monitored in parallel by a high impedance device like a scope ?? I've never heard of them before, thanks for the post.

Comment: @wbg Yep, that's my understanding.